# Appwrite endpoint issue: Client.setEndpoint() not working on render.com server with localhost, what are the alternatives?

Tags: javascript, docker, appwrite, render.com

I use this in my code to access my appwrite local endpoint.

```
import { Client, Account, ID } from 'appwrite';

const client = new Client()
    .setEndpoint('http://localhost/v1')
```

It doesn't work in my render server.
I think it's a problem with the endpoint being localhost, what can it be replaced with

Comment: Have you tried the actual ip of the render server instead or 0.0.0.0? 
or the FQDN https://yourrenderserverdnsname.com/v1